# ec2 nginx enable https

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm using EC2 at aws with a docker-compose and a nginx server

my conf looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://fe:3005;
    }

    location /web {
        rewrite ^/web/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://web:3000;
    }
}
```

and my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I edited the docker-compose and not showing all the services

is there anyway to use the public dns and the https?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 301   https://localhost$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://fe:3005;
    }

    location /web {
        rewrite ^/web/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://web:3000;
    }
}
```

This will always redirect http to https

Comment: actually is not working. It says that i have no cert installed

Comment: @juli1234 thought you already set the cert since you asked about `nginx`. Follow the instructions [here](https://certbot.eff.org/) to install the free cert then. And this should be another question not under this.

Comment: I don't have my own domain, it's just for a challenge that I had to do. So, what I was really wonder is if I could use their cert, like using https://ec2.<ip>.com

Comment: @juli1234 That is not a master domain, but a subdomain which you can use as a `cname` for your master domain. And you will need a master domain to enable SSL. Take a look at route53 and AWS private CA, which would fit your need.